# How to make sure, that only the selected post is changing?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, javascript, wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

So I was able to save the content of each post in an array, thanks to a very good answer on it: [How to localize value of posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269022/how-to-localize-value-of-posts)

I just copied the solution here:

```
function register_and_enqueue_script()
{
    if('myPostType' == get_post_type() && have_posts()) {

    wp_register_script( 'js_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'js/script.js', array(), '1.8.5' );
    wp_enqueue_script('js_script');

    $myCustomValue = array();
    while(have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        $mypostid = get_the_ID();
        $myCustomValue[''+$mypostid] = nl2br(get_post_meta($mypostid, 'custom_value', true));
    } // end while
    rewind_posts();

    wp_localize_script('js_script', 'myCustomValue', $myCustomValue);

} // end if
```

But now I have a new problem: How do I make sure, that only the content of the actual post, where I did the input, is changing? I somehow need to be able to pass the post_id to my JS-Function. But how?

This is the call of the Javascript function:

```
function modify_custom_value()
{
    return '<div>
                <div>
                    <input type="input" onkeyup="doFunction();" "/>
                </div>
            </div>' ;
}
```

This is the function in JS:

```
function doFunction(){
     //alter the content of the post
}
```

Here I do call somefunction():

```
function extend_posts( $content ) 
{
    if ( 'myPostType' == get_post_type() )
    {
        if( $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'custom_value', true ) ) {
           $content = $content . implement_custom_value(); //this works fine
           $content = $content . modify_custom_value(); //this just dont
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'extend_posts' );
```

Any Ideas?

I'm sorry for my many questions :/

Comment: is there an input for every post? if so, why not add the input to your template, so you can pass the id as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, in every post. I want it to be completley independent of the template. It's a plugin.

Comment: you can use this https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

Comment: I've just edited the post.

Comment: what does modify_custom_value do? are you getting any php errors?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any errors. My function is just getting the content of the custom_value, modifys it and then replaces it with the modified version. Basic stuff.

Comment: you are adding custom value to the content twice then? actual and modified.

Comment: btw change + in the array index to a `.`. i changed it in my answer. please post your function code here because it's not clear what is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the post id to your javaScript, i would think of 2 methods.

### Output a variable and then retrieve it using javascript

Let's say you need the post it. You can create a hidden div, and assign the value of your post id to it:

```
<div id="my-post-id"><?php echo get_the_ID(); ?></div>
```

Now you can retrieve this in your script by using this:

```
 var x = document.getElementById("my-post-id").textContent;
```

You have your post id now, proceed to further steps.

### Use `wp_add_inline_script()` to output your script

You can directly add javaScript code to your header or footer by using `wp_add_inline_script()`. Take a look at this example:

```
wp_add_inline_script('js_script','alert("'.get_the_date().'");');
```

Now you can directly use php functions to output contents, use in loops, and more. However you need to enqueue a JS file first and then hook your inline script to it ( in this case, a script that has the ID of `js-script` is being used for hooking ).